# Two CPU cores at 100% utilization after soft lockup on two CPUs, is this normal?

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage, htop

I had two of my CPUs lock up on one of my servers. From `dmesg`:

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [vmx-vcpu-0:6148]
```

and later:

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [vmx-vcpu-0:6148]
```

I'm trying to figure out why this would happen; the processor has 4 cores with hyperthreading, so the OS sees it as 8 cores. But my main question is related to this:

When looking at `htop` post-freeze from SSH, I see that CPUs #2 and #3 (guessing these correspond to #1 and #2 from dmesg) are both stuck at 100% with apparently no processes using them:

[image: htop]

None of the processes were using more than 5% CPU. Why would these display 100% utilization? Are they still considered locked by the kernel?

Comment: What OS/version/kernel/distribution. Also, is this a virtualized guest?

Comment: @ewwhite Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic, bare metal host for some VMs (in VMware Workstation though, not ESX or anything). So far downgrading to Linux `3.5.0-22` seems to resolve the issue, but I can't reliably reproduce it so can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the message reports, this a bug in kernel-level code.

Those CPUs are stuck in a kernel code (vmx-cpu-0) that is not yield()ing control of the CPU for a long period of time.

As far as what to do - open a ticket with VMware. `vmx-cpu-0` looks like their code, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: [So apparently this is not a bug, it's a feature.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009996)